# in line syntax highlighter?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, pre

Is there any Javascript for highlighting codes that show up in a line? What I mean is like the `<a href="code here">` thing that you can also do here.

What is the plugin for that?

Comment: A quick Google search for "javascript syntax highlighter" suggests there are several - have you had a look at any of those?

Answer (score 0):

If you are including code, then the element to use is `<code>...</code>`

http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/bltags_code.htm

If you simply want a monospaced font, then use `<span>` and CSS. (You can also style the `<code>` element, as they do here).